# Making background solid color

Tags: modeling, texturing, color

[image]

How can I make the background color consist of only one color like the picture above?

Usually I made L shaped plane, applied bevel + smooth to make a background, as shown below
[image]

there is still a distinct border between the wall area (darker yellow) and the floor area (lighter yellow), but the first pink image does not have that

What kind of ways would you recommend?

Comment: Hello :). The render was probably done with transparent background, with the pink background added in post. Such approach allows you to use HDRI to light your model, and add shadows in post, while keeping the background color editable without re-rendering.

Comment: Cycles or EEVEE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is less flexible than compositing, but if you're in Cycles, and lazy, you can, for example:

[image]

Split your world material into a mix between 2 colors, one to light the scene, and one to be visible to the camera. Here the scene is lit only by an environment HDRI, with its color tweaked though a *Hue Saturation Value* node.

Sit your object on a plane masked in its 'Object' tab > 'Visibility' panel to be a shadow catcher:

[image]

For this kind of result..

[image]

There are quite a few possible approaches .. maybe 'Shadow Catcher' would be a fruitful search term.

Comment: Hey, that's a great idea to use the shadow catcher :)

Comment: .. but in production, when the client says 'No no no, the background needs to be Pantone 684956' .. yours is the way to have gone.

Comment: exactly what I wanted, much appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you want your background to be all one, uniform color, just plug a color into the Material output without a shader in between. Beware though, this will make the material "shadeless" and it will not be affected by lighting or shadows of any kind:

[image: SolidCol]

Comment: I always appreciate your help! :))